# Are i915 kernel options still required with 13.04?

Tags: i915

My `/etc/default/grub` has these kernel options, which were required to improve battery life when I originally installed 12.04:

```
pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.lvds_downclock=1
```

Are these still required now that I've upgraded to 13.04?

Hardware is a Dell XPS 17.

Comment: Read the full answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 this one is enabled by default

Comment: i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 > i think its enabled by default but i m not sure

Comment: these are not enabled pcie_aspm=force i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1  i915.semaphores=1